# Function assigning loop misses a beat

Tags: numerics

Ive come across this in managing a table, but is seems to be reproducible in simpler forms.

I simply want to iterate a defined function for various values and then work with those at a later time.

```
Do[f[n] = n*40; Print["f[", n, "]=", f[n]], {n, 0.1, 0.2, 0.025}]
```

yields:

```
f[0.1]=4.
f[0.125]=5.
f[0.15]=6.
f[0.175]=7.
f[0.2]=8.
```

Everything in order so far.

```
In[2]:= Table[f[n], {n, 0.1, 0.2, 0.025}]
Out[2]= {4., 5., 6., 7., 8.}
```

Confirmed.

now to access by manual numbers:

```
In[3]:= f /@ {0.1, 0.125, 0.15, 0.175, .2}
Out[3]= {4., 5., 6., f[0.175], 8.}
```

WHAT.

Obviously there's some way the table function assigns numbers that are perceived differently by the kernel.

Maybe addressing it differently:

```
In[4]:= {f[.1 + .075], f[.1 + .025*3], f[0.175*1], f[0.0175*10], f[.025*7]}
Out[4]= {f[0.175], 7., f[0.175], 7., 7.}
```

... so, only increments of `.025`. Obviously.

.. And multiples of 10; but not 10^0. Great.

I've reported the bug to Wolfram, but am interested in it's deeper workings. Can anyone shed light on why this happens?

Comment: It's not a bug; it's a limitation of using inexact numbers. I believe this is a dupe of another question…

Comment: How can .175 already approach the limits of inexact numbers? AFAIK Mathemaica has like 100 significant digits. Edit:... and come to think of it, why does .125 not produce the same error?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting question.  This is a specially handled tag that should only be added by someone else than the original poster (by agreement), after the community has confirmed the bug.

Comment: This is not a bug.  It's just how machine arithmetic works.  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is a frequently suggested reading.  Part of the reason for this behaviour is that the machine numbers are represented in binary internally, which means that numbers such as `0.1` or `0.025` are no exactly representable, the same way as 1/3 = 0.33333... is not exactly representable with a finite number of digits in decimal.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation .. Article's been added to my reading list. But since this is not a bug, how can I avoid incurring this sort of error with assigning function values? Should I define the functions using fractions? This has thrown my automated table manipulation off by a bit.

Comment: @polymachine Mathematica *can* use arbitrary precision arithmetic, but won't do so unless you instruct it to.  If `Precision[someNumber]` tells you `MachinePrecision`, then `someNumber` is a machine precision number with about ~15 digits and no precision tracking.  Machine numbers are much faster to work with as the CPU supports them directly.

Comment: @polymachine How to avoid this problem?  Well, in general, comparing floating points numbers using equality is generally a bad idea in any language.  But Mathematica tries to make things a little easier for us, so it has a high tolerance for comparisons, by default.  Let's say `a=Table[n,{n,0.1,0.2,0.025}][[4]]`.  Now `MatchQ[a,0.175]` returns `False` because it uses exact, bit-by-bit matches.  But `a == 0.175` returns `True` because `==` has some tolerance.

Comment: Perhaps you could exploit `==` somehow to avoid the problem.  But it would be easier to answer this if you gave some more details about why you nee to define `f` this way.  I would go for trying to avoid floating point comparisons in the first place, if possible ...

Comment: Well the reason for defining functions is that i have data depending on 3 variables, so i have to make one of the three into layers so that the  the 3d plot is legible. Therefore I define a function or the few iterations of one of the variables and `ListPlot3D[Table[f[var1],{var1}],{var2},{var3}]`

Comment: @polymachine Sorry, I don't quite understand your last comment.  Also, this is not the right syntax for `ListPlot*` functions.  They should take a single argument only.  Can you post a new question and explain in a bit more detail what you need to do, then ask about how to do it without running into this problem with floating point comparisons?   Alternatively you can also edit this question (and fully rewrite it to it can be reopened), but since this is already marked as duplicate, I think it may be better to just post a new one with a different focus.